# Does a value exist in an Array not working?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I have this function it takes two arrays of objects, `workArr` and `arr`, and match there `id` property and then add up the hours property to store in the `workArr` array.

```
var workArr = [];
var arr = [];
foundID = [];

function blah()
{
   var i = 0;
   var j = 0;

   //Add up the hours
   for( i=0; i < workArr.length ; i++)
   {
       for( j=0; j < arr.length ; j++)
       {
           //Makesure the id's match and the week is within the given time frame
           //ALSO make sure the id hasn't already be visited
           if( cond1 && !(isInArray(workArr[i].id)))
           {
               workArr[j].total = workArr[j].total + arr[j].hrs;
               foundId.push(workArr[j].id);

           }//end if id === id

       }//end for j loop

   }//end for i loop

   printArr(foundId);

}//End blah()

//Checks if the given id has already be found
//returns true or false
function isInArray(id) {
   return foundID.indexOf(id) > -1;
}
```

The problem is when I print out my already visited id array, once this function ends, there are duplicates in it, and there shouldn't be because if a duplicate is found it breaks the `if` condition and doesn't get added to the already found id's. So somehow my `if` condition isn't weeding out the already visited *id's*. Please help me solve this seemingly easy problem.

Comment: `foundId.push(workArr[j].id);` should be `foundId.push(workArr[i].id);`

Comment: You're checking `workArr[i]` and `arr[j]`, but updating totals and pushing based on `workArr[j]`

Comment: @squint actually, that's the part that's *right* - `i` is the loop variable over `workArr` - it's the inner block that's mixing up indices.

Comment: @PaulRoub: Yeah, I focused on the wrong line. Ultimately the issue is a typo.

Comment: @squint & Paul Roub Thank You so much for helping out so quickly, I stared at this ALL day yesterday and got no where. I feel dumb for not seeing an i&j mix-up. Thanks again! +1

Comment: Your *function* should actually *take* two arrays as arguments and *return* a new array; instead of operating on globals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with the help from the comments should be `workArr[i]` not `workArr[j]`

```
if( cond1 && !(isInArray(workArr[i].id)))
{
    workArr[i].total = workArr[i].total + arr[j].hrs; // workArr[i]
    foundId.push(workArr[i].id); // workArr[i]

}//end if id === id
```